# How to add wireless profiles during deployment via MDT

Tags: wifi, mdt

I'm using MDT 2012 to deploy Windows 7 Pro x64. How can I include wireless profiles for several different WiFi networks?  There is no domain, all machines are on a workgroup using group policy is not an option.

Is there a Task Sequence, script or other option to automatically connect to WiFi networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could try exporting the profiles according to linked process and the running the exported executable during a task sequence upon deployment.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4081/easily-backup-import-your-wireless-network-settings-in-windows-7/

There's also a command line option to export/import wireless profile using netsh:

http://mantraaz.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/script-to-add-wireless-profile/

Hope that helps.

Comment: The wordpress site has the solution I'm looking for:  `netsh wlan show networks` Export WLAN profile to XML file `netsh wlan export profile name=”SSID”` Copy the XML file to MDT DeploymentShare. In MDT create a new Task Sequence for Run Command Line: `netsh wlan add profile filename=”c:\temp\filename.xml”`